# Is it possible to renumber a notebook without rerunning it?

Tags: notebooks, indexing

When I prepare a notebook to share with others, I like the numbering of the code cells to start from 0 and to increment predictably to make them more readable, but the only way I know to do this is by restarting the kernel and rerunning the notebook.  However, my notebooks often take tens of minutes to run, so I was wondering if it was possible to get the numbers to look nice a different way?

Answer (score 2):

Does it fit your needs?

```
MapIndexed[
 SetOptions[#, CellLabel -> StringTemplate["In[``]"][#2[[1]]]] &,
 Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], CellStyle -> {"Input"}]
]
```